# Issues with recvfrom in python

Tags: python, sockets, networking, tcp, ip

I'm running a VM with an apache server installed and I'm trying to work out how to do IP and TCP header creation in python. The issue I'm having is that whilst I know (from tcpdump) that my code does in fact create proper headers with a SYN in the tcp header and send them to the server and the server answers with an ACK my code doesn't seem to receive that message.

Furthermore, after the ack there seems to be a second message being sent from the client computer, in which the window size is 0, my code wasn't designed to send this message... Anyway, if that was super rambly (which it was) you may excuse me, it's late and I'm frustrated. Anyway, here's the code

```
import socket, sys
from struct import *

# checksum functions needed for calculation checksum
def checksum(msg):
    s = 0

    # loop taking 2 characters at a time
    for i in range(0, len(msg), 2):
        w = ord(msg[i]) + (ord(msg[i+1]) << 8 )
        s = s + w

    s = (s>>16) + (s & 0xffff);
    s = s + (s >> 16);

    #complement and mask to 4 byte short
    s = ~s & 0xffff

    return s

def IPHeader(SourceIP, DestinationIP, ID):
    Version         = 4
    Header_Length   = 5
    Type_Of_Service = 0
    Total_Length    = 0 #Kernel will fill this in for us
    Fragment_Offset = 0 #If it's split at this point, sum tin wong
    Time_To_Live    = 255
    Protocol        = socket.IPPROTO_TCP
    Checksum        = 0 #Kernel will fill this in for us
    Source_IP       = socket.inet_aton(SourceIP)
    Destination_IP = socket.inet_aton(DestinationIP)

    #We can not pack 4 bit numbers, so we left shift Version and add Header to
    #make an 8 bit number
    Version_and_Header_Length = (Version << 4) + Header_Length

    return pack(
        '!BBHHHBBH4s4s'
        , Version_and_Header_Length
        , Type_Of_Service
        , Total_Length
        , ID
        , Fragment_Offset
        , Time_To_Live
        , Protocol
        , Checksum
        , Source_IP
        , Destination_IP
    )

def TCPHeader(SourceIP, DestinationIP, SourcePort, DestinationPort, SYN, ACK, SeqNr,         AckSeq, WindowSize, UserData):
    Source_Port       = SourcePort
    Destination_Port  = DestinationPort
    Sequence_Number   = SeqNr
    Ack_Number        = AckSeq
    Header_Length     = 5

    #Flags
    Urg               = 0
    Ack               = ACK
    Psh               = 0
    Rst               = 0
    Syn               = SYN
    Fin               = 0

    Window_Size       = WindowSize
    Checksum          = 0
    Urgent_Pointer    = 0

    Header_Length_and_Offset = (Header_Length << 4) + 0
    Flags                    = Fin + (Syn << 1) + (Rst << 2) + (Psh << 3) + (Ack << 4) +   (Urg << 5)

    TCP_Header = pack(
        '!HHLLBBHHH'
        , Source_Port
        , Destination_Port
        , Sequence_Number
        , Ack_Number
        , Header_Length_and_Offset
        , Flags
        , Window_Size
        , Checksum
        , Urgent_Pointer
    )

    Source_IP      = socket.inet_aton(SourceIP)
    Destination_IP = socket.inet_aton(DestinationIP)
    Placeholder    = 0
    Protocol       = socket.IPPROTO_TCP
    Length         = len(TCP_Header) + len(UserData)

    Pseudo_Header = pack(
        '!4s4sBBH'
        , Source_IP
        , Destination_IP
        , Placeholder
        , Protocol
        , Length
    )

    Pseudo_Header = Pseudo_Header + TCP_Header + UserData
    Checksum      = checksum(Pseudo_Header)

    return pack(
        '!HHLLBBH'
        , Source_Port
        , Destination_Port
        , Sequence_Number
        , Ack_Number
        , Header_Length_and_Offset
        , Flags
        , Window_Size
    ) + pack('H', Checksum) + pack ('!H', Urgent_Pointer)

message = IPHeader("192.168.0.100", "192.168.0.103", 0)+TCPHeader("192.168.0.100",  "192.168.0.103", 500, 80, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1000, "")

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_RAW)
s.sendto(message, ("192.168.0.103", 0))

response, addr = s.recvfrom(1000)
SourceIP = unpack('!4s', response[12:16])
print map(ord, (SourceIP[0]))
```

Comment: If you want to receive TCP then you may have to use `IPPROTO_TCP` instead of `IPPROTO_RAW`.  I'm not sure.  http://sock-raw.org/papers/sock_raw is fairly comprehensive but I don't feel up to properly digesting it right now. ;)

Comment: Thing is, I want to read all of the IP packet, the stuff I'm trying to do requires a lot of bit level BS with the IP packets back and forth.

Comment: Maybe a tun or tap device would better suit your needs?

Comment: Maybe, but the point is still that it shouldn't be so difficult to get the raw IP packets...